# Will EABI libraries be updated with primary supported architecture during package update?

Tags: android, arm64, abi

If an Android app initially supports only armeabi-v7a and x86, and in the next future it adds support for arm64-v8a, will a device (which primary and secondary ABIs are arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a respectively) get the arm64-v8a library after an app update or retain it's original v7a libraries? Thanks.

Comment: you distribute your app with multiple APKs, right? Each APK has it's own libraries set, right?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko actually, you don't need to do that.  If you distribute 1 APK with all the libraries, it supports all devices.  Which is the easiest way to make this a yes.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I know that. But depending on the libraries itself, it might be too large for the single APK to hold the libraries for all platforms simultaneously.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it's a fat APK..

Comment: This is actually a side question for the other issue i mentioned here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736243/app-crashes-with-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-for-oreo-devices-with-xamarin-an



I updated my app with arm64-v8a support, and the problem is still there after I updated the app in my testing Oreo devices, but it apparently goes away after I uninstalled it and did a fresh installation. I had 4 Oreo testing devices, and I did that in 2 of them only, so it's a controlled result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An App update will:

- replace all currently present LIBs
- add new libraries
- remove those that are not-more-used from the new APK